# Why does my ATG build fail when using runAssembler?

Tags: macos, atg, oracle-commerce

I recently installed ATG 10.2 on my Mac using the instructions found [here](https://www.sparkred.com/blog/setting-up-atg-on-mac-osx/).

After successfully installing ATG I then tried to compile my ATG code using the `runAssembler` script provided, however I encountered the following error:

> [ERROR] ./bin/dynamoEnv.sh: line 355: -Djava.security.policy=lib/java.policy: No such file or directory

Why does my ATG build fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the spirit of SO I am answering my own question:

It turns out I encountered a known bug with the ATG installers which fail to update the `<DYNAMO_HOME>/home/localconfig/dasEnv.sh` with the correct values (dasEnv.bat for Windows).  The values which you need to add to this file are:

```
# Note: I am using WebLogic (change if you are using jBoss or WebSpere)

export ATGJRE=<YOUR_PATH_TO_JAVA>
# e.g. export ATGJRE=/usr/bin/java

export WL_HOME=<WLS_HOME>
# e.g. export WL_HOME=/Users/my_user/Applications/weblogic/wlserver10_3

export WL_VERSION=10.3.6
# self explanatory ...
```

Please note that this bug affects Windows installs too.  More information can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36434_01/ReleaseNotes.10-1-2/ATGPlatformReleaseNotes/html/s0000installation01.html).